# Running a SQLCMD script from SSIS Execute Process Task with variables

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sqlcmd

I have an .sql file with scripts that include SQLCMD elements.

I need to have it run from an SSIS package.

I was unable to execute it from an "Execute **SQL** Task".

According to this http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic818940-147-1.aspx I should use an "Execute **Process** Task" with:

**Executable:** C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE 
**Arguments:** -S server -U user -P pass -i C:\path\to\file.sql

This is working fine.

But, I need the Arguments to include a Variable. What ever I try, it is failing.

[image: Execute Process Task]

**Arguments:** -S server -U user -P pass -i @[User::FileNameView]

**The error:**

```
[Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" "-S server -U user -P pass -i @[User::FileNameView]" at "", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".
```

**My questions is:** how do I include a variable in the Arguments string? Is there a different approach I should take?

**Extra info:**
SQL Server 2008R2
The reason I need this to be a variables is because I will put the "Execute Process Task" in a "For each loop" to be able to execute all .sql files in a folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to create an expression named Arguments with the value:

```
"-S server -U user -P pass -i " + @[User::FileNameView]
```

You may need to do some type casting if `@[User::FileNameView]` isn't a string.

Comment: This is the error I get when I try that: `[Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" ""-S server -U user -P pass -i " + @[User::FileNameView]" at "", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".`

Comment: Arh - you are correct! I have not used "Execute Process Task" before - so I misunderstood what you ment with *an expression*. It is working correctly now. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was debating if I should explain what to do or not in better detail.  Glad you were able to figure it out!